# Echo only unique values

Tags: php

I've got an XML file that prints out press releases. I want to echo all the years when the press releases have been released, like an archive. Only unique values. The code below prints out all the years. Like "2017,2017,2017,2016,2016,2015,2015,2014" other than "2017,2016,2015,2014,2013".

```
<?php
$file = "file.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);

foreach ($xml->Release as $release) {
   $date = $release['PublishDateUtc']; /* $date is now in format yyyy-mm-ddT06:30:00 */
   $year = substr($date, 0, 4);
   echo $year;
}

?>
```

Comment: Are the values always in order? Then just store the last value in a variable and only echo if the last value isn't equal to the current value.

Answer (score 2):

Make note what dates already printed.

```
$printed = [];

foreach ($xml->Releases as $release) {
    $year = date('Y', strtotime($release['PublishDateUtc']));

    if (!isset($printed[$year])) {
        echo $year;
        $printed[$year] = $year;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can do `echo $printed[$year] = $year`, saves a line of code.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<?php
$file        = "file.xml";
$xml         = simplexml_load_file($file);
$yearArray   = array();
$uniqueArray = array();
foreach ($xml->Release as $release) {
    $date        = $release['PublishDateUtc'];
    /* $date is now in format yyyy-mm-ddT06:30:00 */
    $year        = substr($date, 0, 4);
    $yearArray[] = $year;
}

$uniqueArray = array_unique($yearArray);
print_r($uniqueArray);
?>
```

initialized 2 extra variables and make array of years inside loop.then printed unique array.